# Error 403: Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub: User not authorized to perform this action

Tags: php, push-notification, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to set up a push notification watch but I receive an error response. What authorization I need?

Request:

```
// Google API
$client = getClient();

// POST request    
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch');

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $client->getAccessToken()['access_token'],
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'topicName' => 'projects/xxxx/topics/xxxx',
        'labelIds' => ["INBOX"]
    ))
));
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/xxxx/topics/xxxx : User not authorized to perform this action."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/xxxx/topics/xxxx : User not authorized to perform this action."
 }
}
```

More details:

- The scope used is `GMAIL_READONLY`.
- The suscription and the topic exist and they were created in the same console.
- I tried to publish a new message from the console and it has worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the page:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#grant_publish_rights_on_your_topic

> **Cloud Pub/Sub requires that you grant Gmail privileges to publish
>   notifications to your topic.**
>
> To do this, you need to grant publish privileges to
>   serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com. You can do
>   this using the Cloud Pub/Sub Developer Console permissions interface
>   following the resource-level access control instructions.

(emphasis added)

Comment: How is this `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` user created? I don't have it, but I can't create it either. I'm assuming `serviceAccount` is supposed to be replaced with something, but I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 9):

You have to grant permission to topics.
Go to your topics list
Or click on the below link https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topic.

**Then click on your topic**
[image]

**Then in right side permission tab, click on the ADD MEMBER button**
[image]

Then enter the new member email or If your App have **multiple user** then you can enter **allUsers**. Then Select the role **Pub/Sub Publisher** and click on the **Save** button.

**Note: This will make your topic public.**
[image]

Comment: making it available for allUsers is a security risk, right? I tried `allAuthenticated` users and it still does not work.

Comment: Add to owner additional role `Pub/Sub Admin` for resolve problem with security. And don't add `AllUsers` and `AllAuthorizedUsers` if wan't to have problem with security

Answer (score 8):

dont add `allAuthenticatedUsers` or `allUsers` , that will make your topic public. You might have seen this warning

> This resource is public and can be accessed by anyone on the internet.
>   To remove public access, remove "allUsers" and "allAuthenticatedUsers"
>   from the resource's members.

### SO DONT DO IT

---

Instead add `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`. this will work. 
Reference : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#grant_publish_rights_on_your_topic

Comment: works. Go to Add Member and type in `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com` in the new member input, then select role of `Pub/Sub Publisher` and then save it.

Comment: thx, i love you man