# RpcException: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="User not authorized to perform this action.")

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been trying to send messages to the publisher in Google cloud pub/sub in a .net environment,

```
TopicName topicName = new TopicName("abc", "abc-topic");
PublisherClient publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName);
string messageId = await publisher.PublishAsync("Hello, Pubsub");
```

and getting this error

> RpcException: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="User not
> authorized to perform this action.")

A service account with Pub/sub admin as well as editor, publisher, subscriber and viewer is also assigned as role to it.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin - The resource which I followed

---

Comment: How are you authenticating the publisher client? Have you tried following the steps outlined in https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication?

Comment: You can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133481/error-403-error-sending-test-message-to-cloud-pubsub-user-not-authorized-to-pe . Though the environment is different but the solution can be the same for all . Let me know whether it helps or not.